# How do I use an alias of the static inner class member?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, using

As following codes, I'd like to use an alias to avoid the tedious writing of the static member of inner class NIL.

```
//in RBTree.hpp
template <typename T, typename Comp>
class RBTree{
public:
    struct TreeNode{
       ...
       static TreeNode* NIL = new TreeNode();
       ...
    }
}

//in RBTree_IMPL.hpp
template <typename T, typename Comp>
using NIL = ???
```

I want to use the keyword 'using' to avoid the tedious writing such as :

```
//in BST.hpp
template <typename T, typename Comp>
class BST{
public:
    struct TreeNode{
        ...
    }
}

//in BST_IMPL.hpp
template <typename T, typename Comp>
using TreeNode = typename BST<T, Comp>::TreeNode;
```

As the above, it will be simple. So I want to find a way of using static inner member as above. Thx!

Comment: `using` creates a type alias. `NIL` is not a type, it is a static class member.

Comment: um, if I wanna do this, what should I do?

Comment: Create a keyboard macro for `RBTree<foo, bar>::TreeNode::NIL`. Note that this is only needed outside of the templates scope. Inside the template, `TreeNode::NIL` will be sufficient, or just `NIL` inside `TreeNode`'s scope. Perhaps a few `typedef RBTree<foo, bar>::TreeNode`, here and there, will lessen the pain.

Comment: It works! Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using` is used to create an **alias for a type**. You want to create an **alias for a variable**, which in c++ is a **reference**. Thanks to c++14's template variables the following should work:

```
//in RBTree_IMPL.hpp
template <typename T, typename Comp>
auto& NIL = RBTree<T,Comp>::TreeNode::NIL;
```

Btw.: I don't think the in-Class initialization of NIL will work as you showed in your example, as it isn't a constexpr. You probably have to define and initialize it outside of the class.

**Edit:**

If you are stuck with a c++11 compiler, the best you can afaik do is using a function that returns a reference to the pointer:

```
template <typename T, typename Comp>
auto NIL() -> typename RBTree<T,Comp>::TreeNode*& {
   return RBTree<T,Comp>::TreeNode::NIL;
} 

//usage e.g.:
NIL<int,std::less<int>()-> ...
```

Comment: feel sorry, the grammar is right but It can't work, when I use NIL in other function, I got errors 'NIL' is not declared in this scope.

Comment: @wind2412: Please post the exact code, that produces this problem. I rant he code through gcc6 and it did compile.

Comment: I’ve never used C++17 template variables but doesn’t your code also need a `typename` for good measure since `RBTree<T, Comp>::TreeNode` is a dependent name?

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't notice your C++14 tag. I'm using C11 and I made some test  on online compilers that showed me it can work in C14. Thanks!

Comment: @KonradRudolph  you're right. In fact I wrote this and didn't paste it on. ;)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: As I wrote, template variables are available in c++14.  Regarding the `typename`, I thought so too at first, but both clang-3.9 and gcc 6.3 compile this with `-std=c++14`. Maybe because `NIL` itself isn't a typename?

Comment: You don't need `typename` to disambiguate `TreeNode`, because you then access into it with `::`, which only makes sense for types :)

Comment: @wind2412: I added a c++11 wrokaround

Comment: @Quentin: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: @Quentin It was still necessary in previous versions of C++ but it's possible that the rules for disambiguation were changed.